# perl - How to print utf8 code points for each byte

Tags: perl

I'm trying to print the code points for all possible byte values.

My test file :

```
$ perl -e ' open($fh,">raw_bytes.dat");while($i++<256){ print $fh chr($i-1) } close($fh)'

$ ls -l raw_bytes.dat
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 uuuuu Domain Users 256 Mar 20 15:41 raw_bytes.dat
$
```

What should go into the below `#--->` part so that I print the code points of utf8 $x in hexadecimal?

```
perl -e ' use utf8; open($fh,"<raw_bytes.dat");binmode($fh);
          while($rb=read($fh,$x,1)) { utf8::encode($x);
          #--->
          } '
```

I tried %02x using printf, but it didn't work. Also, I want the solution only using core modules.

Comment: If we take `\x80` as example: do you want the hexadecimal representation of the UTF-8 string (`C280`) or the unicode *codepoint* (`U+00880`)?

Comment: @stefan.. for now, I need utf-8 alone.. but if you know for unicode, pls add it for reference

Comment: This question also has some terminology confusion. Unicode has code points and they go way above 255, UTF-8 is a character encoding for representing Unicode code points as bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unpack('H*')`:

```
$ perl -e '$x="\x80"; utf8::encode($x); print unpack("H*", $x), "\n"'
c280
```

For your example file I get

```
$ perl -e 'open($fh, "<", "raw_bytes.dat"); binmode($fh); 
           while ($rb=read($fh,$x,1)) { utf8::encode($x);
               print unpack("H*", $x), "\n";
           }'
00
01
02
03
...
7f
c280
c281
c282
c283
...
c3bd
c3be
c3bf
```

Variants:

```
$ perl -e '$x="\x80"; utf8::encode($x);
           print uc(unpack("H*", $x)), "\n"'
C280

$ perl -e '$x="\x80"; utf8::encode($x);
           ($r = uc(unpack("H*", $x))) =~ s/(..)/\\X\1/g;
           print "$r\n"'
\XC2\X80

# a little bit pointless example, but assume that $x is a provided Perl scalar....
$ perl -e '$x="\N{U+0080}\N{U+0081}";
           printf("U+%04x ", ord($_)) foreach(split(//, $x));
           print "\n";'
U+0080 U+0081
```

Please remember the difference between

- a scalar holding a raw string: `split(//)` returns **octets**, e.g. `\x80`
- a scalar holding a properly encoded string: `split(//)` returns **characters**, e.g. `\N{U+0080}`

Comment: thank you for quick response.. how to reformat further..  like get the hex chars in upper case C280.. or \XC2\X80 like that?.

Comment: Glad I could help, Updated my answer with some variants.

Comment: BTW: `use utf8;` is not necessary to access `utf8::encode()`.

Comment: The language here needs some clarification, there is plenty of confusion already about character encoding. There is only one type of string (Perl's internal representation is not relevant), but it will contain either bytes (which may be either non-textual binary data, or an encoded representation of text such as UTF-8) or characters (which are decoded unicode codepoints). You use encode and decode to convert between these, and you use bytes to interact with pipes, files, terminals, etc, and characters for text operations.

Comment: Confusing the matter, a string of bytes can be treated as a string of characters (like with split, length, etc), they will be treated as the equivalent Unicode codepoints.

Comment: And you can also treat a string of characters as bytes, which is commonly done by accident when printing decoded characters to a default STDOUT or filehandle for example, and you get wide character warnings/errors if any characters are over U+00FF (255).

Comment: Beware, the unpack solution does not work for multi-byte encodings, it will only output a single-byte value per character, truncating the rest of multi-byte characters values. The solution below with printf doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried %02x using printf, but it didn't work.

You can use

```
printf "%vX\n", $x;
```

According to [perldoc sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

> **vector flag**
>
> This flag tells Perl to interpret the supplied string as a vector of
>   integers, one for each character in the string. Perl applies the
>   format to each integer in turn, then joins the resulting strings with
>   a separator (a dot . by default). This can be useful for displaying
>   ordinal values of characters in arbitrary strings.